# Keras Sequential Compile Function TypeError : compile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, sequential

This is my Keras model

```
model = keras.Sequential
(
    [
        Dense(2, activation="relu", name="L1"),
        Dense(3, activation="relu", name="L2"),
        Dense(4,name="L3")
    ]
)
```

and in the next line i use compile() function on my model

```
model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mse", metrics=[MeanSquaredError()])
```

but i get this TypeError when i run it

```
TypeError: compile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to understand how many input and outputs you have. for example you want to detect the 5 class than your last layer should have 5 as dense attributes.
so add this as model

```
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(224,224,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    #1
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    #2
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    #
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4,activation='softmax')

    ]
)
```

than compile your model

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.01),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```py
model = keras.Sequential
(
    [
        Dense(2, activation="relu", name="L1"),
        Dense(3, activation="relu", name="L2"),
        Dense(4,name="L3")
    ]
)
```

to this:

```py
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        Dense(2, activation="relu", name="L1"),
        Dense(3, activation="relu", name="L2"),
        Dense(4,name="L3")
    ]
)
```

How the Python interpreter reads your code is as follows:

1. `model = keras.Sequential`

`model` just keeps a reference to the `keras.Sequential` class.

2.

```
(
    [
        Dense(2, activation="relu", name="L1"),
        Dense(3, activation="relu", name="L2"),
        Dense(4,name="L3")
    ]
)
```

This creates a tuple of list of `Dense` layers but doesn't store it anywhere. So, this tuple gets garbage collected.